# How to show or hide div or form element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to show or hide fieldset based on the answer selected on YES/NO radio button. I have multiple form elements that has to be shown or hidden based on their corresponding YES/NO radio button. But the code below is not working for me. Could someone help me to correct this problem?

```
<!-- My Form Element  -->

<form>
<fieldset id="question">
  <legend>This is my question</legend>
  <label for="answerYes">Yes</label>
  <input name="answer" class="myradio" type="radio" value="1" />
  <label for="answerNo">No</label>
  <input name="answer" class="myradio" type="radio" value="0" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="subQuestion">
  <legend>This is my question</legend>
  <label for="answerYes">Yes</label>
  <input name="answer" class="subradio" type="radio" value="1" />
  <label for="answerNo">No</label>
  <input name="answer" class="subradio" type="radio" value="0" />
</fieldset>

</form>


// Jquery to show or hide subQuestion

$(document).ready(function(){
  // do your checks of the radio buttons here and show/hide what you want to
  $(".subQuestion").hide();

  $(document).on('click', '.myradio' , function() {
         if ($(this.value).length > 0){ 
            $(".subQuestion").show();           
         }
         else {
            $(".subQuestion").hide();           
         }       
    })

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are checking the length of the value property, which is `1`(because they have valeus `0`0 and `1`) in both the cases, you need to check the value is greater than `0`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do your checks of the radio buttons here and show/hide what you want to
  $(".subQuestion").hide();

  $(document).on('click', '.myradio' , function() {
         if (this.value > 0){ 
            $(".subQuestion").show();           
         }
         else {
            $(".subQuestion").hide();           
         }       
    })

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/udBfX/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".subQuestion").hide();

     $('#question input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if (this.value == 1){ 
            $(".subQuestion").show();           
        } else {
            $(".subQuestion").hide();           
        }       
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `$` in front, to use `this.value` ... and check for value itself and not its  length...

this

```
if ($(this.value).length > 0){
```

should be

```
if (this.value > 0){ //using DOM check if value is greter than 0
```

or

```
if ($(this).val()> 0){  //using jquery
```

**so your final code should be**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// do your checks of the radio buttons here and show/hide what you want to
$(".subQuestion").hide();

 $(document).on('click', '.myradio' , function() {
     if (this.value > 0){ 
        $(".subQuestion").show();           
     }
     else {
        $(".subQuestion").hide();           
     }       
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".subQuestion").hide();

  $(document).on('click', '.myradio' , function() {
         if (this.value == 0){ 
            $(".subQuestion").hide();          
         }
         else {
            $(".subQuestion").show();           
         }       
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/z3rsu/), this is helpful for you. In your code problem in `$(this.value).length > 0)` this line, this is syntax error, difficult to match the value of radio button which is clicked.

```
$(".subQuestion").hide();
  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
         if ($(this).val()== 0){ 
            $(".subQuestion").show();           
         }
         else {
            $(".subQuestion").hide();           
         }       
  });
```